# Call paint recursively appending drawings on a java applet

Tags: java, swing, recursion, applet, repaint

I am attempting to make a graphical representation of my Huffman Code tree. I have the tree's root node and I wrote a printTree() function to recursively call itself and print all the subtrees in the console. 
I made an applet that draws the root of the tree and it's children but I can't figure out how to draw the rest because I can't call paint recursively with parameters. Does anyone know how to go about painting recursively while keeping the old drawing there so I can draw the rest of the tree.

```
 System.out.println("Paint");
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getSize().width -1,getSize().height -1);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString(text, 15, 25);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        //left line
        g.drawLine(ovalCenterx,ovalCentery,leftOvalx+30,leftOvaly);
        //right line
        g.drawLine(ovalCenterx,ovalCentery,rightOvalx+19,rightOvaly);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        //draw left circle
        g.fillOval(leftOvalx,leftOvaly, ovalSize, ovalSize);
        //draw right circle
        g.fillOval(rightOvalx,rightOvaly, ovalSize, ovalSize);
        //draw the root
        g.fillOval(ovalX, ovalY, ovalSize, ovalSize);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        //draw root label
        g.drawChars(label,0,label.length,ovalX+ovalP,ovalY+ovalP);          
        if(labelleft != null)
        g.drawChars(labelleft,0,labelleft.length,leftOvalx+ovalP,leftOvaly+ovalP);
        if(labelright != null)
        g.drawChars(labelright,0,labelright.length,rightOvalx+ovalP,rightOvaly+ovalP);
        if(left){
            setRootCoord(leftOvalx,leftOvaly);
        }
        if(right){
            setRootCoord(rightOvalx,leftOvaly);
```

this is my paint function. I just want to call this function with all the children until I reach the end.

Here is the console version.

```
public void printTree(int counter){
        counter++;
//      System.out.println(this.right + " is this.right");
//      System.out.println(this.left.data.prob);
//      System.out.println(this.right.data.prob);
        if(this.left.data.prob == -1 && this.right.data.prob == -1){
            if(counter > 1)
            return;
            this.left.printTree(counter);
            this.right.printTree(counter);
        }
        if(this.left.data.prob == -1.0 && this.right.data.prob != -1.0){
            System.out.println(this + "my left is -1");
            this.left.printTree(counter);
        }
        if(this.right.data.prob == -1.0 && this.left.data.prob != -1.0){
            System.out.println(this + "my right is -1");
            this.right.printTree(counter);
        }
        if(this.right.data.prob != -1.0 && this.left.data.prob != -1.0){
            System.out.println(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"while keeping the old drawing there.."* Draw it all to a `BufferedImage` then call `repaint()` on the label displaying the image.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: Thank you! , I will look into BufferedImage. I am not forced to use an applet, I can use something else also. I just wanted it to be eventually usable on a website.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I looked up other frameworks and found Vaadin, do you recommend this instead of applet.

Answer (score 1):

If your paint is paint you create your own `paint2(Tree t, Graphics g)`.

Then in `paint2` you do like in `printTree`:

```
if left paint2(left, g);
```

You have to measure the lengths etc though because now you are drawing on 2D space.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you can use graphics in your own functions by passing it from paint. Thankyou, I will attempt that now.

Comment: The recursion is working but the drawing only displays the last drawing of the recursion. Does this need a bufferedImage also?

Comment: dont know - post your code there - could be that you are using different g's or something else

Comment: Never mind, you are absolutely correct. It finally worked! Thank you!